# Amazon MWS rest signature not working

Tags: php, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to get Amazon seller data using the MWS API.The Scratchpad works fine, but when I try my own code, I get errors that indicate my signature isn't quite write. I've tried both GET and post with no luck. Any suggestions?

**ERROR: SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided**

### AMAZON RECENT LIST ORDER REQUEST

```
<?php

$secretKey = '**************************';

$parameters = array();

// required parameters
$parameters['Action']               = 'ListOrders';
$parameters['AWSAccessKeyId']       = '*************';
$parameters['SellerId']             = '*************';
$parameters['SignatureMethod']      = 'HmacSHA256';
$parameters['SignatureVersion']     = '2';
$parameters['Timestamp']            = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$parameters['Version']              = '2013-09-01';

// optional parameters
$parameters['MarketplaceId.Id.1']   = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER';
$parameters['CreatedAfter']         = '2017-10-04T04%3A00%3A00Z';

/**
 * Calculate String to Sign
 * 
 * @param array $parameters request parameters
 * @return String to Sign
 */
function _calculateStringToSign(array $parameters) {
    $data = "GET\n";
    $data .= "mws.amazonservices.com\n";
    $data .= "/Orders/2013-09-01\n";        
    $data .= _getParametersAsString($parameters);
    return $data;
}


/**
 * Convert paremeters to Url encoded query string
 */
function _getParametersAsString(array $parameters)
{
    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    $queryParameters = array();
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $queryParameters[] = $key . '=' . _urlencode($value);
    }
    return implode('&', $queryParameters);
}

function _urlencode($value) {
    return str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($value));
}

/**
 * Computes RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
 */
function _sign($stringToSign, $secretKey)
{
    $hash = 'sha256';

    return urlencode(base64_encode(
        hash_hmac($hash, $stringToSign, $secretKey, true)
    ));
}

/**
 * Builds up the request.
 */
function buildRequest(array $parameters, $secretKey) {
    $endpoint = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01';

    $signature = _sign(_calculateStringToSign($parameters), $secretKey);
    $parameters['Signature'] = $signature;

    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    return $endpoint . '?' . _getParametersAsString($parameters);
}

$request = buildRequest($parameters, $secretKey);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($page);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd very highly recommend using the Amazon Orders SDK. Amazons API can be quite unusual, when not outright broken. The SDK they provide is ugly, but reliable at authenticating and catching errors.

https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html/138-9647438-2994968

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I actually did try this originally. But I have two issues. 

1. the SDK package seems to have some bugs when I try to run it.
2. more importantly the way I want to use the api it's probably easiest to use regular rest requests.

It's a quick fix for an unstable older system (I'm working on a new one) . Adding more files to the code base seems risky since every small change unexpectedly breaks something else.

Comment: @ThisBetterWork you have a relevant username then. Amazon is a mess and I can't highly recommend the SDK enough. It'll save you weeks. As for your second point, quite the opposite. The SDK will keep the API logic outside of your main code base, and the only lines you'll need in the code base are the parameters you're sending and handling the response you get. Good luck.

Comment: Okay @Goose, I'll give the SDK a second chance. Thanks for your help and much needed luck ;>